# Uninterrupted sleep using wait_event_timeout in kernel

Tags: kernel, sleep

I'm trying to put an uninterrupted sleep for 100 milliseconds inside a loop in kernel for network protocol experiment. I tried to use `usleep()` and `delay()`, but they are interrupted whenever a data packet is received.

Then I found about `Wait_event_timeout()` which has the syntax `wait_event_timeout(queue, condition, timeout)`.

I've taken the `condition as x!=y` where `x=1 and y=2`and the `timeout = HZ/10` ( since I want to wait only for 100 milliseconds ).

But what should be the value of `queue`?

Comment: chick this out ... http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144

Comment: @rakeshmalik91 http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144?page=0,1. Here the `smbiod_wait` is a user defined variable or it's already there in the kernel code?